# Text appear to right of links

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to have more text appear next to my links when hovered over, like so;

Link---Text further explaining link

I've used several methods but none are what I need. Heres my code so far;

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?    family=Righteous|Oswald|Slabo+27px' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
<script src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1> MangoPulp</h1>
<header>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="Home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="Purchase"><a href="#"> Purchase</a></li>
        <li class="Products"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li class="SoggyNotions"><a href="#">SoggyNotions</a></li>
      </ul>
 </header>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
background-color: black;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-size: 72px; 
font-style: normal; 
font-variant: normal; 
font-weight: 500; 
}

.nav ul {
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
list-style: none;
text-align: left;
padding: 50;
margin: 0;
}
.nav li  {
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
font-size: 45px;
height: 60px;
} 
.nav a {
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
display: block; 
transition: .4s;
}
.nav a:hover {
color: black;
transition: .6s;
}

.Home a:hover {
line-height: 100%;
font-size: 60px;
background-color: rgb(244, 51, 0)
}

.Purchase a:hover {
line-height: 100%;
font-size: 60px;
background-color: rgb(244, 153, 0)
}

.Products a:hover {
line-height: 100%;
font-size: 60px;
background-color: rgb(255, 204, 0)
}

.SoggyNotions a:hover {
line-height: 110%;
font-size: 60px;
background-color: rgb(204, 204, 0)
}
```

If you look at the code, what I need exactly is extra text to the right of the link to appear in the colored bars when the link is being hovered over. Please and Thank you. 
This my first question I've asked on the site so if anythings wrong please bring it to my attention.

Comment: What is `script.js`?

Comment: http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/ seems to be what you're looking for :)

Comment: I'm using codecademy to easily edit code without needing internet. It supplies you with three windows. One for html, one for css, and another for jquery. My guess is that it's just a link to that.

Comment: Where is the "extra text" coming from?

Comment: You can use pseudo-elements, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/obbjtnL2/, or javascript.

Comment: Well Sexy Turnip I'm not sure. That was part of the problem.

Comment: Nice job Nevermind, ya got it! B-)

Comment: Note that you never close your `<div class="nav">` element, which means you've created invalid HTML (since you're closing the `<header>` before you close its child).

Answer (score 0):

you can add title to the anchor element which is for this purpose.

```
<a href="url" title="Details about link">Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to accomplish with css only.

See example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxezLsv2/1/)

Simplified markup:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="Home"><a href="#">Home<span>Additional Text Explaining the link</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.nav a {
    position: relative;
}

ul.nav a span {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

ul.nav a:hover span {
    display: block;
    width: 220px;
}

.Home a:hover {
    line-height: 100%;
    font-size: 60px;
    background-color: rgb(244, 51, 0)
}
```

With css animations, you could cause this to have various effects (fade, etc) if desired.

Comment: This is the correct answer as long as you don't mind the additional text moving the rest of the page around. However if you're looking to have it appear as a tool tip type of description that hovers over the page rather than pushing the other elements to the right and down on the page you'll need to use javascript and display it absolute positioned.

Comment: I don't see hour your edits change the situation. How can it not affect the document flow without setting it to absolute positioning. And how do you know what position to set it to without using javascript to determine the position of the element triggering the hover. http://jsfiddle.net/fxezLsv2/3/

Comment: @GreggDuncan - check the fiddle, but it all works.  It *does* use absolute positioning.

Comment: I stand corrected. very nice. I think i copied your fiddle before you added the absolute positioning. I'll have to remember this. I'm afraid I'm better with jquery than css.